# How to combine a eclipse project and android studio project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an android studio project, and i found a useful source code from github which is built by eclipse. It there any way I can combine the source file and my own project? I have tried to copy all code to my project but it still not work.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 0):

this link will helpful to you
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: it will open a new project for eclipse but still cant combine the two project together.

Comment: Just take source code from your eclipse project and add it to your android project. Automatically your work will be done

Comment: but if i do so, when i generate the APK file, it cant work in mobile phone. however if i just import the eclipse project into android studio project and generate the APK file, it works in mobile phone